# MySQL query problems with PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo

For some reason, my query is not working, but it did previously.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE urlid = :used');
$stmt->execute(array(':used' => $fname));
$num = $stmt->rowCount();
if ($num == 1 OR $num > 1){
```

ERROR:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE urlid = ?' at line 1' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fbc/urlid.php:100 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fbc/urlid.php(100): PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM ...') #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fbc/urlid.php on line 100`

Comment: How exactly not working? Post errors.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try to change your sql query to

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE urlid = :used");
```

and ensure that your variable $table is defined correctly